# GCP Image in new zone fails to have network connection

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I have created a working ubuntu image in europe-west2-c. This has a static IP (not sure if this is important or not).

Following the instructions on the GCP pages, I created an image of this machine in the us-east1 region as I need an instance in that location.

When I create a VM instance from that image, and start it up, I am unable to SSH to it, ping it, or anything of the sort. Only connection I can make is through the serial console. Checking the differences in configuration between the instance in EU and US has shown nothing, no firewall differences or anything.

I've tried pinging the new instance from other GCP instances and it is unreachable, likewise through the serial console I am unable to ping out.

Answer (score 0):

hope you are doing well.

If I were you I'd check those firewall rules again for the subnet where the new instance is. Verify the IP address of the new instance, which network/subnet it sits in and whether the communication to that instance is allowed from the outside world.

If you have gcloud sdk installed too, try [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) command too from your machine or from cloud console.

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> This has a static IP

Different regions have different IP subnets; make sure the static IP belongs to the correct region. You can check the ranges in your [VPC networks](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list) page.

Also check that your firewall rules correctly reflect your subnet zone's IP range.